# Introduce per-customer personalization in java application

Tags: java

I've searched on internet and here on SO, but couldn't wrap my mind around the various options.

What I need is a way to be able to introduce customer specific customization in any point of my app, in an "external" way, external as in "add drop-in jar and get the customized behavior".

I know that I should implement some sort of plugin system, but I really don't know where to start.

I've read some comment about spring, osgi, etc, can't figure out what is the best approach.

Currently, I have a really simple structure like this:

```
com.mycompany.module.client.jar // client side applet

com.mycompany.module.server.jar // server side services
```

I need a way of doing something like:

1) extend com.mycompany.module.client.MyClass as com.mycompany.module.client.MyCustomerClass

2) jar it separately from the "standard" jars: com.mycompany.customer.client.jar

3) drop in the jar

4) start the application, and have MyCustomerClass used everywhere the original MyClass was used.

Also, since the existing application is pretty big and based on a custom third-party framework, I can't introduce devastating changes.

Which is the best way of doing this?

Also, I need the solution to be doable with java 1.5, since the above mentioned third-party framework requires it.

Answer (score 1):

Personalization depends on the application design strongly. You can search for a pluggable application on the Internet and read a good article (for an example: http://solitarygeek.com/java/a-simple-pluggable-java-application). In the pluggable application, you can add or remove a feature that a user decides. A way for the pluggable application is using the `Interface` for de-coupling of `API` layer and its implementation.
There is a good article in [here](http://www.deadman.ca/articles/pluggableArticle.html)

Comment: I've tried to correct some spelling/grammar mistakes in your post, but I don't understand something: what is a wa? :)

Comment: @eee I understand it's "a way for pluggable application"

Answer (score 1):

Spring 3.1 is probably the easiest way to go about implementing this, as their dependency injection framework provides exactly what you need.  With Spring 3.1's introduction of [Bean Profiles](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html#d0e1293), separating concerns can be even easier.

But integrating Spring into an existing project can be challenging, as there is some core architecture that must be created.  If you are looking for a quick and non-invasive solution, using Spring containers [programmatically](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-instantiating-container-register) may be an ideal approach.

Once you've initialized your Spring container in your startup code, you can explicitly access beans of a given interface by simply querying the container.  Placing a single jar file with the necessary configuration classes on the classpath will essentially automatically include them.

Answer (score 0):

User personalisation is something which needs to be in the design.  What you can change as an after thought if the main body of code cannot be changed, is likely to be very limited.

You need to start be identifying what can be changed on a per user basis.  As it appears this cannot be changed, this is your main limiting factor.  From this list determine what would be useful to change and implement this.

Comment: Currently we rely on parameter tables to determine different behavior in our code, but for limited purposes (field visibility, mandatory fields, etc) but we are hitting this limit, since we are going to need more invasive customization (entire methods, different service calls, etc) so we need a more robust and powerful customization mechanism.